# Is Creep.moveTo() a non-blocking method?

Tags: screeps

```
        // Creep has Energy packed
        creep.say('E: ' + creep.carry.energy);
        if (creep.carry.energy > 0) {
            creep.moveTo(creep.room.controller);
            creep.upgradeController(creep.room.controller);
        }
        // Creep has no Energy
        else {
            creep.moveTo(Game.spawns.Spawn1);
            Game.spawns.Spawn1.transferEnergy(creep, creep.carryCapacity);
            creep.moveTo(creep.room.controller);
            creep.upgradeController(creep.room.controller);
        }
```

The above code should send a creep to upgrade a controller. When it has no energy, it shall go to the spawn and get some. But instead of moving to the spawn, it stays at the controller.

**Question**: Which command is cancelling `creep.moveTo(Game.spawns.Spawn1);`?

Do I have to use the creep's `Memory` and add a kind of state like `isMoving: true` and keep track of that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is exactly what you command the creep to do. The third last line changes the moveTo to the controller. Delete this and the following line.

If you send multiple moveTo to the creep, it executes only the last one. Because it overrides the moveTo commands before.

Comment: For a moment, got confused by the way the scripts are executed. You are right of course, one moveTo per tick.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to cancel a `creep.moveTo()` as it only commands the creep to do a single movement per tick. You stop movement by choosing not to call the `moveTo()` method on the creep.

However, I see why one can mistakenly be led to believe `moveTo()` starts the creep on an autonomous walk along a path - for `moveTo()` calculates the whole path the creep needs to travel to reach the target. Doing that each tick would waste a lot of CPU resources, so it's not exactly intuitive that `moveTo()` only initiates one step of movement per call.

The trick to understanding that this is really what's happening is realizing that `moveTo()` per default caches the calculated path in the creep's `Memory` under the `_move` property and only recalculates a fresh path after a configurable amount of ticks (5 per default, according to the documentation).

That also means the creep's `moveTo()` might need up to 5 ticks (depending on when that happens) per default to realize that an obstacle has blocked the cached path further down the line and so might travel towards the obstacle for a bit until it selects a new unobstructed path.